# redefine a function as wrapper for the old definition

Tags: functions, advice, nadvice

I am trying to modify a package by redefining a function in it.  However, I would like to call the original definition in the new definition. (kind of like extending a constructor in a subclass now that I think of it)

let's say we have this defined

```lisp
(defun hello ()
  "hello")
```

I want to define something like this

```lisp
(defun hello-world ()
  (concat (hello) " world"))
```

except... I want to name the second function `hello` instead of hello world, and just redefine it so that it says " world" at the end, and does that by calling the old function.

Is there a way to give the old function a new name, and then call the old function by its new name, in the new function, which uses the old name?

```
;; first rename hello to _hello somehow

(defun hello ()
  (concat (_hello) " world"))
```

or is there an even better way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want to *advise* the function `hello`, so that it does what you want instead.

See the Elisp manual, node [Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

This code advises function `hello`, *replacing* its definition.  The resulting function invokes the original function (`hello`), concatenates the result of that invocation to `" world"`, and returns that resulting string.

```lisp
(advice-add 'hello :around #'my-hello)

(defun my-hello (original-function)
  "..."
  (concat (funcall original-function) " world")
```

(If the original function itself accepted arguments then you would add them to the list of args to `my-hello` and to the `funcall` sexp.)